# How to send an Enter using webdriverio?

Tags: webdriver

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://google.com')
.setValue('.gsfi', 'webdriver')
//.pause(3000)
.keys('Enter')
//    .click('#btnG')

    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```

The code opens google.com, enters `webdriver`, but `.keys('Enter')` does not send `enter`. Instead the webbrowser remains open and nothing happens. Another attempt was `.click('#btnG')`, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

The parameter passed inside 'keys' function is just a array of characters to be typed. For actions like enter and backspace, appropriate unicode characters must be passed. The unicode character for 'enter' is '\uE007'.

Specific answer to the question:

```
browser.keys("\uE007");
```

Answer from answer '030' is just an alternate way to get the search going. Clicking on the search button by passing the selectors for search button to the click function.

For further documentation on the other keyboard actions:
https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-keyboard-actions

Comment: Could you please add more detail explaining how your solution improves on the solution the OP found and entered as an answer?

Comment: I have improved the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps - that makes this a good answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in FF for me — there's no `.keys` function in FF I think (now 2018). But `element.setValue(\`${value}\n\`);` as suggested in another answer here works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using following function to type some text and click enter after it (using webdriverio 4.0+ with new synchronous syntax):

```
function setValue(browser, element, value) {
  if (browser.options.desiredCapabilities.browserName == "MicrosoftEdge") {
    element.setValue(value);
    browser.keys("\uE007");
  } else {
    element.setValue(`${value}\n`);
  }
}
```

It helps with following problems:

- `element.setValue` doesn't work for Edge (the `\n` character is ignored as enter key wasn't pressed) so we're using `browser.keys`
- `browser.keys` doesn't work for Firefox driver (`Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement`) and it's deprecated so we're using `element.setValue` for non-Edge browsers

Answer (score 0):

**Concise**

A snippet from [this example](https://www.gridlastic.com/webdriverio-example.html) fixed the issue:

```
.setValue('*[name="q"]','webdriverio')
.click('*[name="btnG"]')
```

**Verbose**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://google.com')
    .setValue('*[name="q"]','webdriverio')
    .click('*[name="btnG"]')
    .pause(3000)
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```